# How to access remote object from other computer in remoting

Tags: c#, winforms, remoting

I have a server object as

```
 TcpChannel tcp = new TcpChannel(1234);
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(tcp, false);
        string s = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["remote"];
        RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(TestRemoting.InitialClass1), "TestRemoting", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
        Console.WriteLine("Server is running on 1234 channel...");
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Stop");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

and I am accessing that object in mu client form like

```
 InitialClass1 Icls = (InitialClass1)Activator.GetObject(typeof(InitialClass1), "tcp://localhost:1234//TestRemoting");
```

Now I am keeping my remote object in another computer. How can I access my server object from that computer. If I access the server object from my (local) computer, I will use

`"tcp://localhost:1234//TestRemoting"`

I am using **localhost** here, because my server object and my client is same. So If those two are different, How can I access the server object.
I tried with my another computer IP
as

```
tcp://200.100.0.52:1234//TestRemoting
```

that time I am getting an exception as

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 200.100.0.52:1234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message means most of the time that the client cannot find the service. You can use the following steps to determine where the connection fails:

1. Check if the service is running on the remote machine.
2. Check if the port number is correct.
3. Ping the remote machine from the client.
4. Open a telnet session to the remote machine on the port number of service.

The step on which it fails gives an indication of why it is failing.

Comment: Got it.. I have changed my tcp://200.100.0.52:1234//TestRemoting IP with other computer name.